# is it mandatory to update my version of laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working on a code already made laravel 5.4 and I wonder if it is mandatory to update to the latest version and is it advisable to continue with this version(5.4) there. I really just need only basic stuff on laravel to do my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not required to upgrade the version but it is better if you can keep up, because each version might contain security patches alongside good features and improvements to the existing ones.

Laravel provides very simple upgrade guides that you can follow and if you upgrade them regularly there are almost zero breaking changes.

If you don't like doing it manually then there is a very good service called [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/) which for a couple of bucks can help you with the upgrade.

Comment: thank you very much i work with the 5.4 must i directly put it in 5.8 or do it gradually from 5.4 to 5.5 so on

Comment: The best and easiest way is to do it gradually following the guides. I recently did an upgrade from 5.2 to 5.7 but I installed a new 5.7 project and moved my codebase manually. But those versions had some breaking changes. From 5.4 to 5.8 there are no breaking changes so you can create a separate branch try to upgrade directly, if it goes well then just merge the branch if not do it step by step :) those are my two cents. :)

Comment: how to create a separate branch?sorry I'm really new to all that

Comment: I am talking about `git branch`. So you probably use `git` just `git checkout -b upgrade_branch` and you will be on a separate branch then your master. So anything you do on this branch won't hurt your master branch.